# How to connect to database and update user information using my api ai chat bot

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have created my my chatbot agent, who should be able to update user information in database and also should be able to output some of the user information.

By hard coding the information in the webhook itself i am able to get the information but i am not able to connect to database and retrieve the information.

Can anyone help me with a piece of code, which can connect to any database and able to query the database.

Thanks.

Comment: you should provide more info about the language, database you are using for the project.

Comment: you have to use fulfillment please refer the link https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment#webhook-example

Comment: I am using python language for coding and Database is mysql. I need to retrieve some information and also need to update some of the information from the database using the chat bot agent.

Comment: Actually i am new to python also, which language is best for creating webhook ?